# Host bukkit server with regular server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

My question is simple. I have a Bukkit Minecraft server. Right now there is no Bukkit version compatible with Minecraft 1.3.1.

Is there a way to take my server and host it with the regular Minecraft server until a new version of Bukkit comes out?

If there is, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Never mind I found out a way to downgrade my version

Comment: You are welcome to answer your own question with the solution that worked for you :)

Comment: @James I know thanks I'll do it I just didn't find it as a real answer to my initial question.

Comment: I can give you the basics that you just put a server jar file in the same place as the bukkit one but bukkit also splits out where the different 'worlds' go and that would have to be undone. Assuming no special block ids are going to go missing from bukkit mods then all would be well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that by using windows 7's restoring previous versions system, I could downgrade my Bin folder to be able to go back on my server. Hope this helps someone